Crystal Report - Switch from Document Number to Range
I have a purchase order report that prints for a specific number when the user runs the report.
I need to switch it to first prompt for a vendor code, then show all of the purchase orders for that vendor and print from what the user highlights.
Can someone give me some guidance on how to set this up?
Thanks in advance for the help.
Brian Branco

From Crystal's Help (slightly edited):
To create a parameter with a cascading list of values
1.Open the sample report called Group.rpt.
Sample reports are located on the SAP BusinessObjects Support web site.
2.On the View menu, click Field Explorer.
The Field Explorer dialog box appears.
3.Select Parameter Fields and click New.
The Create New Parameter dialog box appears.
4.Enter a name for the parameter in the Name field(up to 255 alphanumeric characters).
This example uses Supplier City.
5.In the List of Values area, click Dynamic.
6.Enter prompting text for your prompt group in the Prompt Group Text field.
This example uses "Choose the City that your supplier is located in."
Note
Prompt groups let you use cascading list of values for other cascading prompts. For example, if you setup such a list of values for an address prompt, you might want to use the list for both shipping and billing addresses. In this case, you could create two prompt groups for the same list of values; you might call one prompt group Shipping Address and the other Billing Address.
7.Ensure that New isselected in the Choose a Data Source area.
8.Click Insert.
The program automatically expands the Value list. You use this area to define the fields that make up your cascading list of values. This example uses a cascade of Country, Region, and City.
9.From the Value list, select Country.
10.Click the blank field under Country and select Region.
11.Click the blank field under Region and select City.
12.In the Parameters area, click City to bind the field that contains the City value to the parameter.
In this step, you are choosing the field in your cascading hierarchy that should be bound to the parameter field that you are creating. Because this particular parameter is intended to provide Crystal Reports with a city value, you bind the parameter to City.
13.In the Prompt Text field (in the Value Options area), enter additional prompting text for each of the fields in your cascading list of values.
This is the text that appears in the "Enter prompt values" dialog box when the report is refreshed.
14.Click OK.
15.Return to the Field Explorer dialog box, and drag the Supplier City parameter into your report.
